# How to count in this recursive function?

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion, count, nested

I want to iterate over a nested dictionary (which you can see below):

```
bsp = {'bewohnen': {'lemma': 'bewohnen', 'pos': 'VFIN', 'attributes': {'type': 'Full', 'person': '3', 'number': 'Pl', 'tense': 'Pres', 'mood': 'Ind'}},
       'bewirtschaften': {'lemma': 'bewirtschaften', 'pos': 'VFIN', 'attributes': {'type': 'Full', 'person': '3', 'number': 'Pl', 'tense': 'Pres', 'mood': 'Ind'}},
       'die': {'lemma': 'die', 'pos': 'ART', 'attributes': {'type': 'Def', 'case': 'Nom', 'number': 'Pl', 'gender': 'Masc'}}, 'vier': {'lemma': 'vier', 'pos': 'CARD', 'attributes': None},
       'Viertel': {'lemma': 'Viertel', 'pos': 'N', 'attributes': {'type': 'Nom', 'case': 'Nom', 'number': 'Pl', 'gender': 'Neut'}}}

#Code:

def iterdict(d, verbs={"all":0,"pres":0}):
        for k,v in d.items():

            if isinstance(v, dict):
               verbs = iterdict(v, verbs)
            elif k == "tense":
                verbs["all"]+= 1
                if v == "Pres":
                    verbs["pres"]+= 1
            return verbs


        return verbs["pres"]//verbs["all"]


print(iterdict(bsp))
```

I'm interested in counting results (if key gets "tense" and value gets "Pres") in a dictionary, that should be, if recursion-process is finished, returned as

```
return verbs["pres"]//verbs["all"]
```

but while troubleshooting I saw, that it doesn't even count properly, the "verbs"-dictionary stays at 0/0.

Something must be wrong with my recursion, I'm a beginner and I just don't know what I should do to get it done.

Comment: It's bad practice to have mutable default args such as `dict`, `list`, and `set`. Default args are defined once (at function definition time), and any changes made to them in the function will persist to further calls

Comment: would love to get rid of them, i just don't know alternative solutions :)

Comment: It looks like you are overwriting the value of verbs.  Try one of these two approaches:

 (1)  define a dictionary and assign to it in the recursive calls but don't return it (needs a special marker that we are in the top level, so should return something)

(2)  pass in a different dictionary for each recursive call, and merge its results with your "main" (at this level) dictionary

Comment: Is there a need to iterate through the dictionary this way? It looks like you may be able to just search `attributes` using `dict.get`

Comment: Did you inspect/print anything during your troubleshooting? How *deep* into the nested dict did *it* go before returning? What is the function's base case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following, there are two ways to call `iterdict`. If you call it without a second argument, it internal initializes the pair of counters to 0. Otherwise, it mutates the given pair of counts.

The initial call to `iterdict` is made without the counters. The recursive calls take the current pair of counts, which are updated in-place inside the recursive call. The return value of each recursive call isn't really of interest, so it can be ignored.

```
def iterdict(d, counts=None):
    if counts is None:
        counts = dict(all=0, pres=0)

    for k,v in d.items():

        if isinstance(v, dict):
            iterdict(v, counts)
        elif k == "tense":
            counts["all"] += 1
            if v == "Pres":
                counts["pres"] += 1


    return counts["pres"] // counts["all"]
```

Comment: thanks a lot, it worked and i finally understood what i did wrong!